# How to run python programs in Windows 7?

Tags: python, windows

I downloaded this tool to migrate MySQL to PostgreSQL: https://github.com/philipsoutham/py-mysql2pgsql

Python interactive code works properly so the python path is set in the right way.

When I type "py-mysql2pgsql" being in the directory: `C:\Users\me`, the downloaded tool doesn't run but ask me to choose the program to open that file. The same situation when I'm in `C:\Users\me\py-mysql2pgsql`

How can I run this tool properly?

Comment: are you in the python shell when you run this command? Did you do a pip install as suggested in the github notes?

Comment: if you are just in cmd, you have to type python before your filename to run it with python

Comment: Yes, I did pip install. When I try with python before, I get: `can't find '__main__' module in 'py-mysql2pgsql'`

Answer (score 0):

Windows does not understand shebang lines in scripts (#!/usr/bin/env python) like Linux and Unix variants do.  So Windows does not understand that this is a python script, you need to execute python yourself.

If python executable is in your path, you should be able to run:

```
python py-mysql2pgsql
```

If it is not in your path, you should be able to run:

```
path_to_python\python py-mysql2pgsql  (on my machine C:\Python27\python)
```

Note that this applies to any python script on Windows, not just this tool.

Comment: You can use `PATHEXT` to allow what he wants, though. In fact, that's how it's set up for me, probably by the Python installer.

Comment: This file doesn't have an extension though, so not sure this would help.

Comment: Also, I believe that just tells windows what files are executable, not necessarily how to execute them, more entries are needed to associate .py files with python to complete your suggestion.

Comment: While trying to run either `python py-mysql2pgsql` or `path_to_python\python py-mysql2pgsql`, I get: `can't find '__main__' module in 'py-mysql2pgsql'`

Comment: Not familiar with the details of that tool, so not sure what the install dependencies are. This answer addresses the specific situation you described in your question.